# E/AsyncHttpRH: User-space exception detected!

Tags: android-studio

Tengo el metoso ObtDatos el cual es una un envio Post y utilizo el AsysncHttClient como esta en la mas abajo pero cuando lo utilizo me da el error descrito en el encabezado de este mensaje :

> ```
>   public void ObtDatos() {
>         AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
>         String url = "https://hariza.000webhostapp.com/Android_Studio/leer_empresa.php";
>         RequestParams parametros = new RequestParams();
>         parametros.put("tipo", tipo_emp);
>         client.post(this.getApplicationContext(), url, parametros, new  AsyncHttpResponseHandler({
> ```
>
> Cuando utilizo esto me esta dando el siguiente error:
>
> 2020-03-08 12:46:40.883 671-671/com.example.eatbox E/AsyncHttpRH:
>   User-space exception detected!
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.example.eatbox.lista_empresas.CargaLista(lista_empresas.java:50)
>           at com.example.eatbox.lista_empresas$1.onSuccess(lista_empresas.java:64)
>           at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:351)
>           at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:510)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con respecto a el error:

> ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object
>   reference at
>   com.example.eatbox.lista_empresas.CargaLista(lista_empresas.java:50)

Se debe a que la instancia de tu ListView tiene valor null, ya que debes obtener su referencia mediante findViewById(), pero este ListView debe encontrarse el Fragment o Activity que estas cargando, ejemplo

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

En el caso del error

> AsyncHttpRH: User-space exception detected!

Te sugiero revises la respuesta en verdad obtenga resultados.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me ayudo mucho tu comentario